# Creating recurring events mysql fullcalendar

Tags: events, calendar, fullcalendar, recurring, recurring-events

I'm using [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) to create a calendar for my project.

The calendar is working, but I want to create an option to add recurring events. I will create the form for the user to add the event, though how should I create the recurring events?

For example, if a user creates an event to repeat every week, on Wednesday. How do I add that into my Database?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a simple solution, however it can be done. see the folllowing link for details [Recurring Events in fullCalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161654/jquery-fullcalendar-recurring-events) - the gist of it is this

three phases of event handling: add, edit delete. technically view is a phase but it is trivial

on create you need to determine repetition rate, I will leave the form aspect of that up to you

the data you will need is, unique event id, isRecurring(boolean), unique repeat id FOR EACH REPEAT, date of repetition (I prefer to calculate this and store event dates).

edits/delete now become a bit more challenging: the user needs to be prompted to choose between a specific event or all events in the queue. if it is specific. all changes are made to match the unique repeat id. if it is all event, the parent event id is used.

this solution is very high level, but you don't provide any starting point for a code solution