# How to do recurring event using fullCalendar in node.js and mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, fullcalendar, recurring-events

I am creating a scheduling website based on fullcalendar plugin.

We have a requirement to create recurring events. Events will be repeated on weekly or daily basis.

Following is an example of an event that we are trying to achieve
Event Name: Weekly review meeting
Day: Monday
Time: 09:00 to 11:00
Repeat: Weekly (every monday same time for 6 months)

How can I achieve that? We have tried a few options but it does not seem to work.

Can anyone please help with the logic?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29390145/edit) your question and add what you have tried. Then we can try to fix it. This is much easier than coming up with a solution from scratch.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recurring Events in FullCalendar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161654/recurring-events-in-fullcalendar)

Comment: This is not a trivial problem and will require a bit of work, but it's quite possible. I've added an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29393128/728393) to the linked dubplicate.