# Fullcalendar override periodic events on specific day

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use the [Fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) library to create a business hours timetable.

On the backend I could set an event with those params

- start (time)
- end (time)
- day of week (for the day of the week defined)
- when (specific day)

This way, I can set periodic events without specifying "when" or "day of week". That's great. The problem is that I want to be overridden in case of a special day, or special day of week is set.

Below you can find what I'm talking about: the id:1 is a periodic events, but must be override on day dow:6 with the id:2, since is defined as specific for that day of the week only. What I'm looking for is the dow:6 (id:2) shows only the event defined for itself, not the periodic ones. Same behaviour for the specific day, setted with "when" on the id:3

```
        events :    [
            {"id":"1","playingfield_id":"1","dow":null,"when":null,"start":"10:00:00","end":"14:00:00", rendering:"background"},
            {"id":"2","playingfield_id":"1","dow":"6","when":null,"start":"14:00:00","end":"15:00:00", rendering:"background"},
            {"id":"3","playingfield_id":"1","dow":null,"when":"2015-05-05","start":"15:00:00","end":"16:00:00", rendering:"background"}
        ]
```

You can see the code working at in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/aLfweku0/).
Someone knows if this is possible? At the moment

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29393128/728393) of mine.

Comment: @slicedtoad your answer gives me lot of posibilities. Thank you so much! I will try to update this question with a solution based on your answer.