# Recurring Overnight Events in FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using the FullCalendar plugin for JQuery, and I am trying to create a recurring event that spans multiple days. In this instance I want a recurring event that starts at 10am Monday and ends at 3am Tuesday.

I have researched how to do recurring events, [such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161654/recurring-events-in-fullcalendar), but I can't seem to get it to work across multiple days.

For example, creating a recurring event on the same day like this works fine:

```
{
  start: '10:00',
  end:   '15:00',
  dow: [1]
}
```

However, trying to span the event overnight doesn't work ( I mean Monday 10:00 to Tuesday 03:00 ):

```
{
  start: '10:00',
  end:   '03:00',
  dow: [1]
}
```

It just seems to create a 2-hour event.

Is it possible to do what I want? And if so, how?

[image]

Comment: I have made some considerable changes to your question to try and explain the issue better, I hope you are happy with these changes. Hopefully this will get your question some more attention. For what it's worth, I have done a little research and I can't seem to find a solution. It may be that this is a limitation of the plugin

Comment: @musefan thank you. english became clear(good).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer I gave on the page you linked ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29393128/728393)) should work. You just need to use the right times.

This won't work

```
{
  start: '10:00', //starts at 10 on monday
  end:   '03:00', //ends at 3 on monday? gets ignored
  dow: [1]
}
```

Instead:

```
{
  start: '10:00', //starts at 10 on monday
  end:   '27:00', //24+3 is handled correctly.
  dow: [1]
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/duu0dx2t/102/)