# How to print php variable inside javascript and change php's array format

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I use Chart.js to present my data.

```
var data_2 = {
    datasets: [{
        data: //print php var here,
        backgroundColor: [
            '#00c0ef',
            '#f56954',
            '#00a65a',
        ],
    }],
};
```

I want to change my array format from something like

Array ( [jml] => 833 ) Array ( [jml] => 6 ) Array ( [jml] => 18 ))

to `[833, 6, 18]`

My questions are how to print my php variable inside javascript and how to change php's array style to javascript's array style. Thanks

Comment: Assuming `$arr = [833, 6, 18]` you can do `data: <?= json_encode($arr) ?>,`

Comment: You have 3 arrays not 1, poss dupe: [How to get an array of specific “key”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994497/how-to-get-an-array-of-specific-key-in-multidimensional-array-without-looping/7994555#7994555)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_encode()` is well suited for injecting data into JavaScript:

```
<?php
$data = [["jml"=>833], ["jml"=>6], ["jml"=>18]];
$arr = array_column($data, "jml");
$var = json_encode($arr);
?>

<script>
var data_2 = {
    datasets: [{
        data: <?= $var ?>,
        backgroundColor: [
            '#00c0ef',
            '#f56954',
            '#00a65a',
        ],
    }],
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**In php part:**

```
<?php
$dataArr = Array ( Array ( 'jml' => 833 ), Array ( 'jml' => 6 ), Array ( 'jml' => 18 ));

$chartData = '';
foreach($dataArr as $data){
    $chartData .= $data['jml'].',';
}

$chart = '['.rtrim($chartData,',').']';
?>
```

Then change in your script to:

```
var data_2 = {
    datasets: [{
        data: <?php  echo $chart; ?>,
        backgroundColor: [
            '#00c0ef',
            '#f56954',
            '#00a65a',
        ],
    }],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple way**
I had already tired this way,its working.See this link but,I have use laravel  [Recurring events in FullCalendar with Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32736486/recurring-events-in-fullcalendar-with-laravel/51281929#51281929)

```
var data_2 = {
    datasets: [{
        data: [<?php echo $var[0],$var[1],$var[2] ?>],
        backgroundColor: [
            '#00c0ef',
            '#f56954',
            '#00a65a',
        ],
    }],
};
```