# How do I go about creating an event every hour and everyday?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, loops, fullcalendar

I was wondering on to have an event every hour on every day in the AgendayDay view. I customized the timeslots to be an hour long. I will be filling the title/description with values from the database. I seen some questions answered for recurring events every monday for an example.

EDIT: I get the recurring event every monday as an example. **I'm asking how do you create a different event for every HOUR without creating an event manually.**

Something like this but for everyday. Of course, not every event will have the same value.[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15161654/830125

Comment: There's no better solution than creating 24 and have them repeat?
`events: [{
    title:"My repeating event",
    start: '10:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
    end: '14:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)
    dow: [ 1, 4 ] // Repeat monday and thursday
}],`

Comment: Couldn't you just push 24 repeating events in a loop?

Comment: Wouldn't that have a huge load on the calendar?

Comment: If each of 24 events must have a unique value, I don't see how you could do anything other than create 24 unique events.

Comment: Is there a way to not show or not render events on the monthView of the calendar?

Comment: I would recommend updating your question to clarify that your requirement is to not render events in the month view, or post a new question regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(timeIncrement = 0; timeIncrement < 24; timeIncrement++){
            $scope.events.push({
                title: 'Rooms Available [' + 11 + ']',
                start: new Date(yearClicked, monthClicked, dayClicked, timeIncrement)
            });
        }
```

Is what I came up with. This is inside a if statement when an available date has been clicked.