# Is it possible to edit only one event of repeating/recurring event in fullcalendar(Angular)?

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

How can i edit only one event without edit all recurring events in angular.

```
 events: [
{
  title: 'blueEvents',
  daysOfWeek: [ '4' ],
  startTime: '10:45:00',
  endTime: '12:45:00'
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fullcalendar's support for recurring events is rather limited. For added functionality, you can use the RRule Plugin: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/rrule-plugin

If you want to use the Interaction plugin (i.e. be able to drag, drop and resize events), you can use the groupId parameter to specify when all events within a definition will move together, as per the documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/recurring-events

Theoretically, in order to alter only one instance of the recurring event, you could clone it and edit it as a separate element and then change the original recurring event to exclude the date you are altering.

Perhaps these question might help you: [Fullcalendar recurring event exclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32883044/fullcalendar-recurring-event-exclusion)