# Displaying events based on dates in fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have events which are recurring weekly but the recurring events are displaying before current week as well. Can the recurring events be rendered only from current week and beyond? Currently Im using the following code to display my recurring week but it is not working.

My recurring event is as

```
events: [
id: 1,
title: Hello,
start: 2016-01-26T02: 00: 00.000-07: 00,
end: 2016-01-26T05: 30: 00.000-07: 00,
allDay: false,
eventType: availability,
rendering: background,
color: black,
dow: [1,4]
```

],

And My code to attempt my criteria is

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
             return (event.start>=moment().startOf('week'));
            }
```

Comment: Take a look at [recurring-events-in-fullcalendar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161654/recurring-events-in-fullcalendar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use moment property,this should help:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
if(((moment(event.eventDate))>($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate').endOf('week'))) {
element.hide();
}       
 }
```

Comment: Wow!! it worked. I used moment.js to implement these changes and worked like a charm.