# Recurring events in FullCalendar ASP MVC

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am using jQuery FullCalendar as my calendar. I want to add a function that can recurring my events. I am not sure if FullCalendar has this function available or we need to customize ourself. I am using ASP MVC. I start with this code

```
public ActionResult Create(string start)
{
    var a = startdt.ToString("dddd");
    if (repeat == "daily")
    {
        if (a == "monday")
        {
            for (start, till, ++days)
            {
                //not sure what to do
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I want it be like for every `monday` after start date, the session is automatically book by this person. I am pretty sure I am not doing this right since I dont find any reference to follow. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it supports a complete solution but take a look here. [[Recurring Events in FullCalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161654/recurring-events-in-fullcalendar?rq=1][1])