# Option to just use days in the week with fullcalendar library

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am using the Fullcalendar library, and I have an array of JavaScript objects:

```
arr = [{"monday":{"start_time":9,"end_time":10.5},"title":"English for Beginer"},{"tuesday":{"start_time":8.5,"end_time":10},"title":"English for Beginer"},{"wednesday":{"start_time":8.5,"end_time":10},"title":"English for Beginer"}]
```

According to the doc, I can set up my event sources like this:

```
{
    events: [
        {
            title: 'Event1',
            start: '2011-04-04T09:30',
            end: '2011-04-04T10:30',

        },
        {
            title: 'Event2',
            start: '2011-05-05T9:30',
            end: '2011-04-04T10:30',
        }
        // etc...
    ],
    color: 'yellow',   // an option!
    textColor: 'black' // an option!
}
```

However, I only have the days in a week in my JavaScript objects, like monday, tuesday, wednesday, etc as you can see. Therefore, I am wondering if there is a way for me to configure my event sources like the following:

```
{
        events: [
            {
                title: 'Event1',
                start: 'MondayT09:30',
                end: 'MondayT10:30',

            },
            {
                title: 'Event2',
                start: 'TuesdayT9:30',
                end: 'TuesdayT10:30',
            }
            // etc...
        ],
        color: 'yellow',   // an option!
        textColor: 'black' // an option!
    }
```

I have been looking for a solution for a while, but still can't find one. Any suggestions or idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without date set in event.start variable fullcalendar will not be able to display your event. Please see fullCalendar [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs1/event_data/Event_Object/)

Event.Start date is required field. Your JSON needs some information about date when your event starts.

When you want to create recurring event, you can use event.dow parameter like this:

```
events: [
  {
    title: 'All Day Event',
    start: '2017-05-22'
  }, 
        {
    title: 'Sviatok práce',
    start: '00:00 ',
    end: '24:00',
          dow: [1,2,3,4,5]
  },
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I already know this. So, that is only option I have? Do you know any other schedulers/calendar javascripts working with just days?

Comment: no ... i am using FullCalendar where Date is required. In fact i don't understand how you want to display in any calendar event using only weekday without exact date.

Comment: Cool. It is understandable when I just want to generate a timetable for students. There is no need to specify dates for their courses since these courses will repeat until the students finish them.

Comment: ok, so this maybe helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161654/recurring-events-in-fullcalendar