# How to Show events that span multiple days as individual events on each day that it spans?

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using a fullcalendar.js Version 2.4.0 and fullcalendar spans long events I.e Events which are From 3rd May to 5th May are show as a long Event Streched all over, but what I need to show is to span multi - day Events as Seperate Event on Each day 
For Example in Image attached Below A Event Children's Petting zoo is a 3 day Event, so it is shown 3 times seprately on these days which is giving it a clean look. I want to show in the same way.

[image: Event calendar showing multi-day event]

How can Acheive this as given in Screenshort with Fullcalendar in All the Views.

See Screenshort of my calendar and point 2 which I want to do.

[image: multi day events]

Comment: think of it as the concept of repeating events. You'd have to change the way you feed data to the calendar. This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29393128/5947043 shows how to do it, with a bit of extra code and a slight modification to the event data format.

Comment: I am not a js expert , and don't have idea how to change this in fullcalendar.js ,by looking into the HTML i only understands that for recurring events it is adding colspan="2" in <td class="fc-event-container">  which stretches it for two days can you pls help me to achieve daily recurring events.

Comment: You can just follow that answer I linked to, there's nothing really to add to it. You don't need to mess with the HTML or change the core fullCalendar.js - it's all done through the structure of your event data and the options you pass to the calendar when you declare it in your own code. If you try to implement that answer and you get stuck, then edit this question with the code you've written, and the problem you're having, then tag me and I'll try to help.