# jQuery full calendar generate appointments for complete month

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, appointment

Hi all need a help with jQuery fullcalender.

```
$("body").on("click", '#schedule-appointments', function(){
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y =date.getFullYear();
    var newEvent = {
        title: 'NEW EVENT',
        start: '10:00',
        end: '14:00',
        dow: [ 1,5 ],
        ranges: [{start: moment('2017-11-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),
            end: moment('2017-11-01','YYYY-MM-DD').endOf('month') }]
        $("#calendar1").fullCalendar("renderEvent", newEvent, false);
  });
```

This is the method I have used so far but still exceed the month.
[image]

I am new to the jQuery full calendar any guide line please.

Thank you.

Comment: Unless that feature has been added recently you have to create your own recurring events

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a "how do i program..." site. We as a community expect you to do your own research. Asking this type of question will farm downvotes. Please do some research then ask a specific question about programming and we would be glad to help.

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for the information :) .

Comment: @catbadger  I wanted some direction for the question may be the way I asked is miss leading.  Anyway thanks for valuable instructions. :)

Comment: Thanks for adding code.

Comment: @catbadger thanks for guiding to the  right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"ranges" is not a standard part of fullCalendar's event object.

Did you perhaps get the idea from an older question, such as this one: [Recurring Events in FullCalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161654/recurring-events-in-fullcalendar)?

If you want it to work you have to also include the custom code in the eventRender callback, which is the code which reads the data from the ranges and decides whether or not to actually display the event.

```
eventRender: function(event){
    return (event.ranges.filter(function(range){ // test event against all the ranges

        return (event.start.isBefore(range.end) &&
            event.end.isAfter(range.start));

    }).length)>0; //if it isn't in one of the ranges, don't render it (by returning false)
},
```