# Laravel Collection push() not properly working

Tags: php, json, laravel, collections, fullcalendar

I am trying to duplicate an item in a collection based on the date range. For example, I have a JSON of  this:

```
{
"title": " 200",
"start": "2017-12-20",
"endx": "2017-12-25",
"equipment": "Chairs",
"quantity": 200
}
```

Now I want to duplicate 6x because there are 6 days from 12-20 to 12-25.  Like this:

```
{
"title": " 200",
"start": "2017-12-20",
"endx": "2017-12-20",
"equipment": "Chairs",
"quantity": 200
}

{
"title": " 200",
"start": "2017-12-21",
"endx": "2017-12-21",
"equipment": "Chairs",
"quantity": 200
}

{
"title": " 200",
"start": "2017-12-22",
"endx": "2017-12-22",
"equipment": "Chairs",
"quantity": 200
}

{
"title": " 200",
"start": "2017-12-23",
"endx": "2017-12-23",
"equipment": "Chairs",
"quantity": 200
}

{
"title": " 200",
"start": "2017-12-24",
"endx": "2017-12-24",
"equipment": "Chairs",
"quantity": 200
}

{
"title": " 200",
"start": "2017-12-25",
"endx": "2017-12-25",
"equipment": "Chairs",
"quantity": 200
}
```

I want this because of the answer from my previous question: [Repeat events on FullCalendar base on date start and end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47862871/repeat-events-on-fullcalendar-base-on-date-start-and-end?noredirect=1#comment82696565_47862871)

Here is my code:

```
$events = Event::all();

        foreach ($events as $i => $event) {
            if($event->start != $event->endx)
            {
                $date = $event->start;
                $end = $event->endx;
                while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end)) {
                    $new = [];
                    $new = $event;

                    $new->start = $date;
                    $new->endx = $date;

                    $events->push($new);

                    $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
                }
            }
        }

        return $events->all();
```

But the only output I got is that it repeats 6x based on the last date "2017-12-25". Like this:

```
{
"title": " 200",
"start": "2017-12-25",
"endx": "2017-12-25",
"equipment": "Chairs",
"quantity": 200
}

{
"title": " 200",
"start": "2017-12-25",
"endx": "2017-12-25",
"equipment": "Chairs",
"quantity": 200
}

{
"title": " 200",
"start": "2017-12-25",
"endx": "2017-12-25",
"equipment": "Chairs",
"quantity": 200
}

{
"title": " 200",
"start": "2017-12-25",
"endx": "2017-12-25",
"equipment": "Chairs",
"quantity": 200
}

{
"title": " 200",
"start": "2017-12-25",
"endx": "2017-12-25",
"equipment": "Chairs",
"quantity": 200
}

{
"title": " 200",
"start": "2017-12-25",
"endx": "2017-12-25",
"equipment": "Chairs",
"quantity": 200
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is:

`$new` is an object. The `$new` that you've pushed to that collection is the same `$new` that you will be using on the next iteration. To further describe the situation:

```
$a = new stdClass;
$a->name = "foo";

$myArray = [$a];

var_dump($myArray);
// array(1) {
//  [0]=>
//  object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
//    ["name"]=>
//    string(3) "foo"
//  }
//}

$a->name = "bar";
var_dump($myArray);
// array(1) {
//  [0]=>
//  object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
//    ["name"]=>
//    string(3) "bar"
//  }
//}
```

`$new` is being passed by reference to the `push` method, or some would say, assigned by reference.

That's the magic that is happening in your case, to fix that, you should push a cloned object of `$new`.

You can trace the `push` code here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L1129

Change `$events->push($new);` to `$events->push(clone $new);`