# jquery fullCalendar Event adds extra month when ranging from e.g: March to April

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, fullcalendar

I am making this project in ASP.NET MVC 5.

I made something people like to call multipleDayEvents which displays like this

[image: MultipleDayEventImg]

Now when I make one of those events range from 31st of March - 4th of April or anywhere that it jumps a month. it creates 2 events only on the client side.
One that does exactly what I want, from 31st to 4th, but the other one acts like an allDay event, spanning from 31st of march to 4th of Mei. so a month too far.

It looks like this:

[image: calendarBug]

this is the code of the eventSources where I think the problem lies. But I have the full code available [in this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chc1eru6/)

```
eventSources: [
            {
                events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '@Url.Action("List/medewerker_melding")',
                        data: "",  //Hier kan eventueel de userID komen van de gebruiker die ingelogt is.
                        //completely take out 'data:' line if you don't want to pass to webmethod - Important to also change webmethod to not accept any parameters
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (doc) {
                            var events = [];   //javascript event object word hier gemaakt
                            var obj = doc;  //.net returned json gewikkeld in "doc"

                            $.each(doc, function (index, obj) { //voor elke event in de database, push event in de kalender

                                var start = new Date(obj.start);
                                var end = new Date(obj.end);

                                var diff = (Date.parse(end) - Date.parse(start)); // end - start returns difference in milliseconds
                                var days = diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;  // get days
                                var days = (Math.round(days) + 1);


                                if (days > 1 && obj.allDay == false) {

                                    obj.isMultipleDays = true;
                                    var addDays = 0;

                                    MultipleDayEventStart = [];
                                    MultipleDayEventEnd = [];


                                    //Create multiple days
                                    for (i = 1; i <= days; i++) {

                                        var tmpDate = new Date();
                                        tmpDate.setTime(start.getTime());
                                        tmpDate.setDate(start.getDate() + addDays);
                                        start.setDate(start.getDate() + addDays);



                                        var tmpDate2 = new Date();
                                        tmpDate2.setTime(end.getTime());
                                        tmpDate2.setDate(tmpDate.getDate());


                                        tmpDate = tmpDate.toString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
                                        tmpDate2 = tmpDate2.toString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');


                                        MultipleDayEventStart[i - 1] = tmpDate;
                                        MultipleDayEventEnd[i - 1] = tmpDate2;

                                        AllMultipleDayEventsStart.push([obj.id, MultipleDayEventStart]);
                                        AllMultipleDayEventsEnd.push([obj.id, MultipleDayEventEnd]);

                                        addDays = 1;

                                    };

                                } if (!obj.isMultipleDays) {
                                    events.push({
                                        id: obj.id,
                                        title: obj.title + ", " + obj.meldingOmsch,
                                        start: obj.start,
                                        end: obj.end,
                                        desc: obj.desc,
                                        user: obj.user,
                                        melding: obj.meldingID,
                                        allDay: obj.allDay,
                                        color: color
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    for (d = 0; d < days; d++) {
                                        events.push({
                                            id: obj.id,
                                            title: obj.title + ", " + obj.meldingOmsch,
                                            start: MultipleDayEventStart[d],
                                            end: MultipleDayEventEnd[d],
                                            desc: obj.desc,
                                            user: obj.user,
                                            melding: obj.meldingID,
                                            allDay: obj.allDay,
                                            color: color,
                                            isMultipleDays: true,
                                            day: d
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                                console.log('-----------------EVENTS-----------------')
                                console.log(events);
                            });

                            callback(events);

                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', events, true);
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
        {
            url: '../../Scripts/Feestdagen.js',
            desc: 'feestdag',
            color: 'green',
            allDay: true,

        }
        ],
```

This code simply checks how long an event lasts. if it's longer than 1 day, e.g. 4 days. it starts looping and adding 1 day to the start date and storing that date in an array untill 4 days have been added. That looks something like this: {start:2018-03-14, start:2018-03-15, start:2018-03-16, start:2018-03-17}. then loops the event.push, creating 4 events with the same ID's but selecting the corrosponding dates from the array. as you can see below.

[image: ConsoleLogProblemEvent]

Though the first item on the list has an end date of 2018-05-01 where it should be 2018-04-01.

The issue does not lie in the controller since the dates of the event in the database are correct, and there aren't 2 events created.

Also when I check the server output, the dates are correct

```
{
 "id": 96,
 "title": "K. Keesen",
 "desc": null,
 "start": "2018-03-31 08:30:00",
 "end": "2018-04-04 17:00:00",
 "user": 15,
 "meldingOmsch": "spoedlijn",
 "meldingID": 12,
 "allDay": false,
 "isMultipleDays": false
}
```

the way a user creates an event is by clicking on a date, then a bootstrap modal opens with a form inside then when pressed on submit, it fires this script:

```
$('#eventModal #save').on('click', function () {
        var start = $('#eventModal #startDate').val();
        var end = $('#eventModal #endDate').val();
        var diff = new Date(Date.parse(end) - Date.parse(start)); // end - start returns difference in milliseconds
        var days = diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;  // get days
        if ($('#eventModal #start').val() == ($('#eventModal #end').val()) && days == 0) {
            alert("Een event kan niet beginnen en eindigen op de zelfde tijd!");
            return false;
        } else {
            $('#eventModal .meldingForm').submit();
        }
    })
```

this script simply checks if someone hasn't tried to make an event that ranges from the same date to the same time (e.g 24th march 8:30 -> 24th march 8:30(this will produce an error))

Thanks

Comment: the things which are key to this, and are missing from the question, are 1) the raw data you're getting back from the server initially, 2) the precise rules and expectations about what this quite lengthy transformation code is supposed to achieve, or 3) precise and clear enumeration of what the correct output should be. In other words, we've got the code, and the incorrect output data, but we haven't got the input data or the expected output, or the business rules. All of these are necessary in order to understand, reproduce and then fix the problem. Thanks.

Comment: The requirements are particularly interesting because I wonder if there is a simpler way to do what you need - what you've got there is quite long. For instance, have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161654/recurring-events-in-fullcalendar

Comment: haha I get your point but I'd rather give too much information than too little. let me edit a bit

Comment: You have given too little information to fix the issue, that's not what I'm saying. What I meant was it's a lot of code just to do some manipulating to create multiple events from one. The link I gave you shows a less verbose way of defining and displaying recurring events.

Comment: but what I created wasn't for recurring events. I don't have any events that need to be shown every week. I made this script to prevent events from having a duration of e.g 42 hours

Comment: instead those events are now split into several dates, displaying 4 (depending on what the user inputs) seperate events

Comment: ah I see. It looked like you were splitting one event spanning multiple days into a series of single events each spanning a single day within the  start/end dates of the bigger event. Is that not the basic scenario here? Is there something else to take into consideration? Like I said before, you haven't made the exact requirements clear. BTW that code in the link I gave you allows for daily repetition as well as (or instead of) weekly.

Comment: I eddited, tho the question became longer ^^"

Comment: sorry, that is the scenario indeed. when someone creates an event from 8th of march 8:30  till 12th of march 17:00. the database recieves a range of start: 08-03-2018 8:30, end:12-03-2018 17:00. and then when clientside, it creates events for each day, spanning from 8:30 to 17:00.  this all happens UNLESS an event only lasts 1 day OR when `allDay=true`

Comment: ok well the code I suggested should work very nicely for that. You might just need to tweak it for the all-Day bit. And of course you have to slightly change the structure of the JSON coming from the server, but that shouldn't be too tricky. IMO it would be easier than debugging and tidying the wall of code above.