# Full Calendar business hours until property

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, primeng

Im using the p-schedule component from PrimeNg, its fully dependent on the FullCalendar library.

Im building a calendar for small business, one of the requirements is building a management calendar that track the employee working hours.

I built the component and attach to it the employees working hours schedule, but the specific requirements needs an until property i.e

> This emplyee is working from 8:00 AM to 2:00 PM in Sat and Wed for 2 years.

the first part of the requirement is done, but I faced an issue with the **2 years** part.

does the FullCalendar business support this approach?

if not, what is the alternative or workarround for this issue?

Comment: So you want that the businessHours attr is only valid for 2 years? I not think fullcalendar has a function like this (btw I am not sure if this is really a good idea). But as a workaround you can set the visibleRange to 2 years.

Comment: since the calendar generally only displays a few weeks at at time, at the most, you could perhaps handle the changing of views (viewRender callback is a possibility), check the date and change the business hours. Another approach is to ditch businessHours, use background events (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events) and combine it with a small bit of extension code which allows you to support recurring events: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161654/recurring-events-in-fullcalendar

Comment: thanks, the provided question helped alot