# Fullcalendar recurring event with rrule is not working

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4, rrule

I am using fullcalendar 4.4.0 and everything working fine except rrule.
If i try with simple recurrence, it is working, but rrule recurrence not working.
let me share my code

```
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/rrule@4.4.0/main.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/core@4.4.0/main.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/interaction@4.4.0/main.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/daygrid@4.4.0/main.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/timegrid@4.4.0/main.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/resource-common@4.4.0/main.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/resource-daygrid@4.4.0/main.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/resource-timegrid@4.4.0/main.min.js"></script>
    <scritpt src="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/moment@4.4.0/main.min.js"></scritpt>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/interaction@4.4.0/main.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('public/plugins/datepicker-master/dist/datepicker.js')}}"></script>
```

**The code for generating event is as follows.**

```
             function makeEventFromBook(book) {
                var event={};
                var start_time_object=new Date(book.start_date+" "+book.book_time);
                var end_time_object=new Date(start_time_object.getTime() + 
                parseInt(book.duration)*60*1000);
                var start_time=start_time_object.toISOString();
                var end_time=end_time_object.toISOString();
                if(book.name==='null' || book.name==null)
                    book.name='';
                event={
                        id:book.id,
                        resourceId: book.provider_id,
                        // start: start_time,
                        // end:end_time,
                        title:book.name,
                        overlap:false,
                        backgroundColor:`${book.service_item_id==0 ? '#ff0000' :  '#1f1dd0'} `,
                        textColor:'#fff',
                        borderColor:'transparent',

                        rrule: {
                            count: 13,
                            freq: 'weekly',
                            interval: 1,
                            byweekday: [ 'mo', 'fr' ],
                            dtstart: '2020-03-01',
                            duration:"01:30"
                        },
                        groupId:book.id,

                        extendedProps:{
                            user_id:book.user_id,
                            user_name:book.user_name,
                            user_email:book.user_email,
                            user_phone_number:book.user_phone_number,
                            duration:book.duration,
                            book_date:book.book_time,
                            from_admin:book.from_admin,
                            service_type:book.service_type,
                            service_item_id:book.service_item_id,
                            provider_id:book.provider_id,
                            comment:book.comment,


                        }
                }
                return event;
            }
```

**What is issue here?
If anyone has experience, please help me.**

I am sharing my calendar how it is being showed
[image]

There is no recurring event here.

Example of event data:

```
events=[ { id: 117, resourceId: 3, title: "Personal", backgroundColor: "#ff0000 ", rrule: { count: 13, freq: "weekly", interval: 1, byweekday: [ "mo", "fr" ], dtstart: "2020-03-01", duration: "01:30" }, groupId: 117 }, ]
```

Comment: give us some sample data for the `book` variable please. Then we can accurately reproduce the problem. And also please show your calendar code.

Comment: I shared my data structure

Comment: I shared my data structure already, i just tried to check with sample recurring rule, but it was not worked.

Comment: Thanks but I didn't ask for the data **structure** - I can already see that. I actually asked for some **data** :-). The output of `JSON.stringify(book)` would do nicely.

Comment: One thing I noticed though...you've commented out the `start` property of your event. FullCalendar will not show an event at all if it doesn't have a start. even if the event is recurring, the recurring patter still has to start at some time. So when you say it's "not working" do you mean that the recurrence doesn't happen, or that the event does not show up at all? You didn't clarify that. (As a general point, in future, instead of saying something simply is "not working", it's far more helpful to say exactly what the code is doing, and what you expected it to do instead.)

Comment: Event is just rendering, just recurring not working. Becoz recurring was not working, I just commented start date to see how it works.

Comment: events=[
            {
                id: 117, resourceId: 3, title: "Personal",  
                backgroundColor: "#ff0000 ",
                rrule: {
                    count: 13,
                    freq: "weekly",
                    interval: 1,
                    byweekday: [
                        "mo",
                        "fr"
                    ],
                    dtstart: "2020-03-01",
                    duration: "01:30"
                },
                groupId: 117
            },
        ]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209088/discussion-between-baimaoli-and-adyson).

Comment: I shared my screenshots to show how it works with my code. Event is being displayed, but there is no recurring events here.

Comment: I am talking to you in the chat you started, please go there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you include the rrule Javascript library file, and the fullCalendar rrule plugin file, and include the plugin in your calendar config.

You also need to remove the "duration" property from your rrule, because that's not a valid rrule option, and will cause an error.

At the time of writing, you can get the rrule file from https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rrule@2.6.2/dist/es5/rrule.min.js

Here's a working demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/poJWLzB

Demo code, for reference:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: ["interaction", "dayGrid", "timeGrid", "resourceTimeline", "rrule"],
    header: {
      left: "prev,next today",
      center: "title",
      right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay"
    },
    events: [ { id: 117, resourceId: 3, title: "Personal", backgroundColor: "#ff0000 ", rrule: { count: 13, freq: "weekly", interval: 1, byweekday: [ "mo", "fr" ], dtstart: "2020-03-01" }, groupId: 117 } ]
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I did not include javascript library, just included full calendar rrule library. That was issue. and after i included javascript rrule library, it is working well now. Thanks for your support.. Best luck for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue!I was working with @fullcalendar/ @5.1.0 (ie.,@fullcalendar/core, @fullcalendar/rrule and so on) , the recurring events didn't display. Then I changed all my fullcalendar dependencies (@fullcalendar/) to @5.2.0 and used rrule @2.6.4. It is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to show  **a day, daily, weekly, every two weeks and monthly** events with a tooltip on mouse hover event.

In this example you can see how we can set up **rrule in FullCalendar**.

Visit here- https://stackoverflow.com/a/68770685/9673996