# FullCalendar - repeating a single event on every day without being told to

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-4

I'm playing with a basic implementation of FullCalendar. But with the code below (copy and paste into a file). My 'meeting' repeats at the given time every single day.
I should have 1 event against Fred, 3pm to 6pm on March 1st. Not repeating.

This happens regardless of startRecur/endRecur properties.
The only thing that had effect was daysOfWeek property. Setting a value meant it only appears on those days.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks Mick

```js
function run() {

  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: ['resourceTimeline'],

    defaultView: 'resourceTimelineWeek',
    resources: [{
        id: 1,
        title: 'Fred'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Jane'
      }
    ],
    events: [{
      id: '1',
      resourceId: '1',
      title: 'Meeting',
      allDay: false,
      start: '2020-03-1',
      end: '2020-03-1',
      startTime: '15:00',
      endTime: '18:00'
    }]
  });

  calendar.render();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/core@4.4.0/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/resource-common@4.4.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/timeline@4.4.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/resource-timeline@4.4.0/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/core@4.4.0/locales-all.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/core@4.4.0/main.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/timeline@4.4.0/main.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/resource-timeline@4.4.0/main.min.css">





<body onload="run()">

  <div id='calendar'></div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify the `startTime` and `endTime` properties mentioned in the [Recurring events documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/recurring-events), then fullCalendar ignores the standard `start` and `end` properties completely for determining the placement of the event, and relies instead on the recurrence-related properties (startTime, endTime, startRecur and endRecur).

You *could* specify this single event using the recurrence syntax, like this:

```
startRecur: '2020-03-01',
endRecur: '2020-03-02',
startTime: '15:00',
endTime: '18:00'
```

But it's a bit nonsensical if you don't actually want any recurrence.

If you just want a normal single-occurence event, then don't use the "recurring events" properties. Just specify the date and time in the `start` and `end` properties in the normal way which is [clearly documented](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object) and shown in countless examples in the fullCalendar documentation and demos:

```
start: '2020-03-01 15:00',
end: '2020-03-01 18:00',
```

I'm not clear how you ended up deciding to use properties which are only mentioned on the documentation page about recurrence, in order to try and define a non-recurring event.

Anyway here's a working demo:

```js
function run() {

  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: ['resourceTimeline'],

    defaultView: 'resourceTimelineWeek',
    resources: [{
        id: 1,
        title: 'Fred'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Jane'
      }
    ],
    events: [{
      id: '1',
      resourceId: '1',
      title: 'Meeting',
      allDay: false,
      start: '2020-03-01 15:00',
      end: '2020-03-01 18:00',
    }]
  });

  calendar.render();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/core@4.4.0/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/resource-common@4.4.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/timeline@4.4.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/resource-timeline@4.4.0/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/core@4.4.0/locales-all.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/core@4.4.0/main.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/timeline@4.4.0/main.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/resource-timeline@4.4.0/main.min.css">





<body onload="run()">

  <div id='calendar'></div>


</body>
```

Comment: Thanks A - I literally just worked it out. Pretty embarrassing. I'm not sure why I thought 'start' was only the date. As you say it's pretty clear in the docs that it's both. And I guess I didn't read the info on startTime.

Comment: OP is not wrong, I faced the exact issue and was using startTime, even though I never opened the docs for recurring event. It was this page https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing

Comment: @MustafaHanif ok but in that page too it clearly mentions that startTime and endTime are for recurring events. I don't think it's confusing, but if you disagree you could ask the maintainers of fullCalendar to clarify the documentation - raise a ticket on their GitHub page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to show **one day, daily, weekly, every two weeks and monthly** events with tooltip on mouse hover event.

Visit here- https://stackoverflow.com/a/68770685/9673996