# In Fullcalendar, is there any way to display all-day events individually per day without spanning?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I have a specific request to display calendar All Day events *without* using the day spanning. E.g. If an event is on Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday, instead of [......Event.......] it should show up as [Event Event Event]. Is there any way to do this? I am lost as to how to override the spanning behaviour. Ideally I'd avoid editing the core, especially as I'd like to keep the default rendering for other users. (Currently using Full Calendar v3 but would upgrade if necessary.)

I also considered using the ListView style and displaying it in columns, but it is table-based and not laid out in a way that makes it easy to transform that way. Is there a way to override the ListView display functions without, again, modifying fullcalendar.js?

Comment: You should use recurring events instead - then each event will show up separately on each day. Unfortunately since you're using an old version of fullCalendar, this isn't supported out of the box - in v4 onwards there is a built-in feature for recurring events. So you can a) upgrade and then follow https://fullcalendar.io/docs/recurring-events, b) just create 3 individual events instead of 1, or c) follow this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29393128/5947043

Comment: P.S. Beware the upgrading from v3 may involve a lot of work - there is a fundamental change of approach in v4: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/upgrading-from-v3. And then v4-v5 involves a few more changes, but less major: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v4 . It's worthwhile overall, but just make sure you plan a bit of time to do it, especially if your calendar is more than just a very basic setup.